# How to rename a COM DLL

Tags: c#, windows, dll, com, interop

Is it somehow possible to rename a COM DLL?

Here is the scenario,

- I've a COM DLL named ABC.dll.
- Registered it using regsvr32 command
- Added to the references of a .NET project
- ABC.dll is now present in references list

That's all right. Now lets un-register this ABC.dll, and remove it from references.

After that I rename that DLL to XYZ.dll, and register it again using above mentioned command.
Then I add XYZ.dll as a reference in same/different .NET project.

Now in references list I can still see ABC.dll. It should have been XYZ.dll.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't actually add a reference to the DLL, the compiler uses the *type library* of the COM component.  Its registration GUID is recorded in your project file.  Could be a .tlb file but many components built with a native tool chain have the type library embedded inside the DLL as a resource.  Type libraries have a name, that is what you see back as the namespace of the types.  So renaming the DLL does not also rename the type library, what you see is entirely normal and there is no "workaround" for it.  Only the author of the component can name the library.

Comment: The dll has a entry point(s) and renaming the file does not change the entry point(s).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. You may post your answer.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. You may post your answer.

Comment: Hmm, this question is not answerable.  You are asking for a "workaround" but there is no workaround and it is completely unclear why you need one.  Just complete the Q+A yourself with what you learned today.